# ideavim loses focus with nnoremap / /\v

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, ideavim

I am using following mapping in my vimrcs to simplify searches.

```
nnoremap / /\v
vnoremap / /\v
```

but when I tried to use this in IDEA, after pressing "/" command line "popup" with expected `/\v` appears, but the keyboard focus is completely lost. Meaning that i can neither continue with entering search term nor there is simple way to go back to code editor.

Is there solution are mappings as those not supported?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-681. Feel free to vote for it.